# How to warm up an ASP.NET web application so it doesn't take so long to boot up when navigated to?

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-applications

crowdsourcing here: I work with a legacy Classic ASP product. In order to do transaction checkout, we open up an iFrame (yeah, I know...blecht!) and then run the checkout server pages on a secure server in the iframe. The checkout project is an ASP.NET web application.

Here's the problem: Initial bootup of the application takes a bit of time. Sometimes 10 seconds. Once it's warmed up, it never needs warming again and works in a flash. How do I speed up the initial load?

My idea (it's a doosey): Whilst the user is clicking within the Classic area of the website, call a secure web service on the checkout server to tickle the web application to life. Then, when the user actually hits the thing, it is warmed up.

Any other ideas?

Comment: From which version of IIS is it being served?

Comment: IIS 6.0.  We are migrating to 7 soon enough.

Comment: Have you investigated (or are you able to investigate) why the Checkout App takes so long to initialise?

Comment: I initially thought it had something to do with the AES decryption, but that doesn't make any sense, being that every time after the first boot up, it loads in under a nano-second.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your version of IIS, I might have suggested the IIS 7.5 Warm-Up Module, but it looks like it's been discontinued. You could do a few things:

1. Write a service (Windows service, scheduled task, etc.) that pings the application every *x* minutes or once in the morning to keep it alive or wake it up.
2. Extend the idle timeout for the application pool
3. Spawn a new thread (or launch a pop-under, or something that can do work for you in the background) when it's first started that goes off and does the warm-up procedure while you're navigating your way towards the page with the iframe, and then have it close itself once it gets a response.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public page aspx or ashx page that returns an RSS feed that tells the time. Then subscribe to that RSS feed with something like Feedburner, which polls RSS feeds. Since the RSS feed is different each time, it will get polled more often.

In 1.1 you had to visit every page to avoid the initial compile tax. I'm pretty sure in 2.0+ you only have to visit one page and it doesn't have to be the one you care about.

Comment: Yes. From the most recent market share stats I've seen, there is a less than 5% chance you are running ASP.NET 1.1